# Take current BehaviorSubject value only when ActivatedRoute changes

Tags: angular, rxjs

`this.draftService.getDraftConfig()` returns an Observable that is stored as a BehaviorSubject in my service. How would I get the current value of the BehaviorSubject *only* when my `ActivatedRoute` params change? i.e. if the `ActivatedRoute` params don't change I do not want to trigger the subscription.

```
    this.configSub = combineLatest([
      this.activatedRoute.params.pipe(
        map(x => x['environment'])
      ),
      this.activatedRoute.parent!.parent!.params.pipe(
        map(x => x['tableName'])
      ),
    ]).pipe(
      switchMap(([environment, tableName]) => {
        this.environment = environment;
        this.tableName = tableName;
        return this.draftService.getDraftConfig()
      }),
      take(1)
    ).subscribe(config => {
      this.config = config;
      this.initForm();
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `withLatestFrom` pipe with the `ActivatedRoute` params Observable.

```
this.configSub = this.activatedRoute.params
  .pipe(withLatestFrom(this.draftService.GetDraftConfig())
  .subscribe(([params, config]) => {
    // Other stuff
    this.config = config;
    this.initForm();
});
```

This will emit a value when the params change and grab the latest value from the `Observable` returned from `this.draftService.GetDraftConfig()`.

> https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/withLatestFrom